# Angular - How to apply user roles permission on the side menu

Tags: angular

In my Angular-14 application, I have these roles from the API:

1. Admin
2. Teacher
3. Student

I use userRole = localStorage.getItem('role') to display this. Each user can only have a role.

I want to apply the roles to the sidebar, so that only the specified roles will see the allowed menu.

sidebar.ts:

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostBinding('class') classes: string = BASE_CLASSES;
  public menu = MENU;
  userRole = localStorage.getItem('role');

  constructor(
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
export const MENU = [
  {
      name: 'Dashboard',
      iconClasses: 'fas fa-tachometer-alt',
      path: ['/admin-dashboard']
  },
  {
      name: 'Student List',
      iconClasses: 'fas fa-users',
      path: ['/admin-dashboard/students-list']
  },
  {
    name: 'Payments',
    iconClasses: 'fas fa-calendar',
    children: [
        {
            name: 'Fee List',
            iconClasses: 'far fa-circle nav-icon',
            path: ['/admin-dashboard/fee-list']
        },
        {
            name: 'My Fees',
            iconClasses: 'far fa-circle nav-icon',
            path: ['/admin-dashboard/myfees']
        }
    ]
  }
];
```

sidebar.html:

```
  <nav class="mt-2" style="overflow-y: hidden">
      <ul
          class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column"
          data-widget="treeview"
          role="menu"
          data-accordion="false"
      >
          <app-menu-item
              *ngFor="let item of menu"
              [menuItem]="item"
          ></app-menu-item>
      </ul>
  </nav>
```

I want to to achieve these:

1. All users to view Dashboard
2. Only Admin and Teacher to view Student List
3. Only Admin to view Fee List
4. Only Student to view My Fees

How do I apply userRole() to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you look into guards. The docs are here: https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access

Comment: Add an extra attribute to your menu items, like `roles: ['student', 'admin']`, and later just [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the menu according to the logged user access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would still want to look into [route guards](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/angular-basics-canactivate-introduction-routing-guards) to lock down the actual route but you can conditionally add menu items

```js
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostBinding('class') classes: string = BASE_CLASSES;
  userRole = localStorage.getItem('role') as "admin" | "teacher" | "student";
  public menu = [
    {
        name: 'Dashboard',
        iconClasses: 'fas fa-tachometer-alt',
        path: ['/admin-dashboard']
    },
    ...(this.userRole === "admin" || this.userRole === "teacher" ? [{
        name: 'Student List',
        iconClasses: 'fas fa-users',
        path: ['/admin-dashboard/students-list']
    }] : []), 
    ...(this.userRole === "admin" || this.userRole === "student" ? [{
      name: 'Payments',
      iconClasses: 'fas fa-calendar',
      children: [
          ...(this.userRole === "admin" ? [{
              name: 'Fee List',
              iconClasses: 'far fa-circle nav-icon',
              path: ['/admin-dashboard/fee-list']
          }] : []),
          ...(this.userRole === "student" ? [{
              name: 'My Fees',
              iconClasses: 'far fa-circle nav-icon',
              path: ['/admin-dashboard/myfees']
          }] : [])
      ]
    }] : [])
  ];

  constructor(
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: This works. However, I would suggest you modify your code to simply `filter` the `menu` variable and its childrens and also add a "roles" attribute to every menu item... currently your code is for the most part unreadable.